# Changing color of tabs titles in vim color files

Tags: vim

In my custom `color.vim` file there are multiples entries like these ones:

```
:hi VertSplit gui=none cterm=reverse
:hi Folded ctermfg=grey ctermbg=darkgrey
:hi FoldColumn ctermfg=4 ctermbg=7
:hi IncSearch cterm=none ctermfg=black ctermbg=darkgreen
```

However I can't seem to find the two responsible for the colors of name of files in the tabs, and in the selected tab.

What are those two entries ? If no idea, where to find a list of all entries with what they correspond to ?

Comment: I had not searched enough, already answered on SO:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238113/customising-the-colours-of-vims-tab-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not searched enough, this is already answered on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238113/customising-the-colours-of-vims-tab-bar

In a nutshell I should alter these different settings `TabLineFill`, `TabLine`, `TabLineSel`, and `Title` :

```
:hi TabLineFill ctermfg=LightGreen ctermbg=DarkGreen
:hi TabLine ctermfg=Blue ctermbg=Yellow
:hi TabLineSel ctermfg=Red ctermbg=Yellow
:hi Title ctermfg=LightBlue ctermbg=Magenta
```